# Import the class Splitter from a *.pyd file in Cython

Tags: scikit-learn, cython

I am trying to write a subclass of the sklearn's class sklearn.tree._splitter.Splitter. 
I wrote the following subclass in cython:

```
from libc.string cimport memcpy 
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()

from sklearn.tree._splitter import Splitter, SplitRecord

from ._utils import rand_int

cdef double INFINITY = np.inf

cdef class StochasticSplitter(Splitter):
    """Splitter for finding a split stochastically."""
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (StochasticSplitter, (self.criterion,
                                     self.max_features,
                                     self.min_samples_leaf,
                                     self.min_weight_leaf,
                                     self.random_state,
                                     self.presort), self.__getstate__())

    cdef int node_split(self, double impurity, SplitRecord* split,
                        SIZE_t* n_constant_features) nogil except -1:
        """ Find the best split on node samples[start:end]
        Returns -1 in case of failure to allocate memory (and raise MemoryError)
        or 0 otherwise.
        """
        " My Logic...."

        # Return values
        split[0] = chosen_split
        n_constant_features[0] = n_total_constants
        return 0
```

But when I tried to compile the file, I got the following errors:

> 'Splitter' is not a type name

And

> 'SplitRecord' is not a type identifier

Why does it happens?
And how can I import Splitter and SplitRecord so I could use them in cdef class?

Notes:
- I don't have the .pyx and .pxd of the _splitter module, so I can't cimport these classes. I only have the .pyd file.
- I want to define this class as a cdef class (and not a regular, pythonic, class) since the function node_split uses pointers (and I don't know how to use pointers in python)

I searched in the internet and here, and  found samiliar questions, but none of the answers in them helped me...
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *need* to `cimport` the files:

```
from sklearn.tree._splitter cimport Splitter, SplitRecord
```

`import` happens when your module is run, so does not provide any information to Cython. It also does not provide information about the internal structure of the classes, which Cython needs. `cimport` happens when Cython compiles the module, so lets Cython know that `Splitter` is a `cdef class`, and therefore you should be able to inherit from it.

The information Cython needs is really not available in the compiled `.pyd` file. You have to have the `.pxd` file. It also needs to be installed with the correct path for Cython to find it (i.e. in a directory called `sklearn\tree\` and on the Python path).

Given that `sklearn` is open source there's really no reason not to have the necessary files. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html. If your issue is that you can't install sklearn fully because you don't have admin permissions then you can install it to a user directory directory instead:

```
pip install --user -U sklearn
```

You're better off installing sklearn properly than copying the files one-by-one.

Comment: But when I tries to cimport the classes, I get the following errors while compiling: **cannot find cimported module 'sklearn.tree._splitter'** and **'sklearn\tree\_splitter.pxd' not found** (I really don't have the .pxd file, only the .pyd file).
Isn't there another way to import the module?

Comment: I should possibly have read the end of the question more carefully - you do mention cimport.... Why can't you download the file https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pxd ? There really isn't another way - Cython needs this information to make a `cdef class`

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't thought about that. I will try this. I thought about downloading _spliter.pyx, but _spliter.pyx cimport _criterion.Criterion, and _criterion itself cimport about 4 other modules, so it seemed quiet endless. Will downloading only the .pxd file will be enough?

Comment: Edit: Ok, I tried it (I download _splitter.pxd and _criterion.pxd tp the same directory as my file, and in my file cimported them and imported the _splitter.pyd from the sklearn pakect), but now it gives me the error **'sklearn\tree\_splitter.pxd' not found** on the line `from sklearn.tree._splitter import Splitter, SplitRecord`...

Comment: See edit. I think you should just install sklearn properly rather than downloading the files one at a time

Comment: I thought I did it (I installed the version of scikit-learn provided by pycharm). But I searched and found here [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html) that there are more ways to install it. I will try them. Thanks for your help!